Forward context-menu events to sibling-divs
I have a web-application where the user can create visualization elements within a div.
In one example the user created a div that's clickable and has a hover-event, but is a sibling to, and displayed on top of, elements that have context-menu events on them.
Is it possible to have the element on top (element with class me in the snippet) respect on-click events while still transparently forwarding context-menu events to the elements that appear under the mouse cursor (elements with class cousin in the snippet), even though they are siblings?
I've tried capturing context-menu events in the editor div, finding all direct children that are under the mouse-cursor and a dispatching a new context-menu event on them, but since the elements that I want to receive the events are nested within the sibling, this event doesn't reach them.


let editor = document.getElementById("editor");
editor.oncontextmenu = e => {
  // Skip opening the browser context-menu.
  e.preventDefault();

  for (let i = 0; i < editor.children.length; i++) {
    let currentChild = editor.children[i];
    if (currentChild == e.target) {
      // Avoid executing the event on the element that received it.
      continue;
    }

    let currentRect = currentChild.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (currentRect.left < e.offsetX &&
      currentRect.top < e.offsetY &&
      currentRect.right > e.offsetX &&
      currentRect.bottom > e.offsetY) {

      // Problem here is that the new event is only sent to the sibling, not further down to the texts.
      // Since the text boxes have context menu event, not the sibling, this won't do anything.
      // I would preferrably like to just re-execute the right-click while the browser calculates the destination.
      // The current way requires every layer to have this custom logic in 'oncontextmenu',
      // which is not possible in my scenario.
      let ev = new MouseEvent('contextmenu', {
        screenX: e.screenX,
        screenY: e.screenY,
        clientX: e.clientX,
        clientY: e.clientY,
        ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
        shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
        altKey: e.altKey,
        metaKey: e.metaKey,
        button: e.button,
      });
      currentChild.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
  }
}

let header = document.getElementById("header");
document.onmousemove = e => {
  header.innerHTML = 'Header text<br/>x: ' + e.pageX + '<br/>y: ' + e.pageY;
}
#header {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#editor {
  position: relative;
}

.sibling {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 75px;
}

.me {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.me:hover {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: green;
}

.nephew {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 9px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.cousin {
  color: yellow;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
<header id="header">Header text<br/> x: ?<br/> y: ?</header>
<div id="editor">
  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="nephew">
      <div class="cousin">
        <div class="text" oncontextmenu="alert('context-menu on \'Value 1\'')">Value 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cousin">
        <div class="text" oncontextmenu="alert('context-menu on \'Value 2\'')">Value 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="me" onclick="alert('clicked \'me\'')" oncontextmenu="alert('context-menu on \'me\'')"></div>
</div>



Same snippet in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7gnqsm51/9/
The project does not currently use JQuery, so I would prefer solutions without it.

What's the real question here? I think this problem would be better described in terms of what you are trying to achieve the in the UI, rather than what you want to do with with the DOM.

Edited to clarify what the question actually is.
